# How to calculate no. of binary strings containg substring “00”?

Tags: combinatorics, binary

I need to calculate no of possible substrings containing "00" as a substring. I know the length of the binary string.

Eg: for a string of length 4, possible substrings are: 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 1000 1001 1100

I just need the number of possible combinations, not enumerate all of them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of binary numbers with two consecutive zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76472/); [How many $N$ digits binary numbers can be formed where $0$ is not repeated](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261326/); [How many bit-strings of length 7 have exactly 2 consecutive zeros](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69139/); [Probability of having at least $K$ consecutive zeros in a sequence of 0s and 1s](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245947/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ that do contain $00$, and let $b_n$ be the number that don't; of course $b_n=2^n-a_n$, but it's actually easier to determine $b_n$. Consider a string of length $n$ that does not contain $00$. If it ends in $1$, it can be obtained from a string of length $n-1$ that does not contain $00$ by appending a $1$. If it ends in $0$, it can be obtained from a string of length $n-2$ that does not contain $00$ by appending $10$. Assuming that $n\ge 2$, every string of length $n$ that does not contain $00$ is obtained in exactly one of these two ways, so $b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$. Clearly $b_0=1$, since the empty string does not contain $00$, and $b_1=2$. The recurrence is the same as that for the [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), $b_0=F_2$, and $b_1=F_3$, so in general we have $b_n=F_{n+2}$ and therefore

$$a_n=2^n-F_{n+2}\;.$$

Using the closed-form expressions in the linked article, we can write

$$a_n=2^n-F_{n+2}=2^n-\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\varphi^{n+2}-\widehat\varphi^{n+2}\right)=2^n-\left\lfloor\frac{\varphi^{n+2}}{\sqrt5}+\frac12\right\rfloor\;,$$

where $\varphi=\frac12\left(1+\sqrt5\right)$ and $\widehat\varphi=\frac12\left(1-\sqrt5\right)$.

Comment: @Czechnology: You’re welcome!