# How to find the moment generating function of this scenario.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Suppose a computer can generate either 0's or 1's, and I want to get two consecutive 1's. The computer generates 0's with probability of $1/2$ and 1's with probability of $1/2$. Let's call the number of times required to get two consecutive 1's $K$. I need to find the moment generating function of $M$. I know that $M_K(t)=E[e^{tK}]$, and I'm thinking that if I can express $K$ in terms of each individual trial, I would be able to find the mgf. I know each individual trial is an independent Bernoulli. I think that if I call $X_i$ the outcome of each trial, then $K=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ where $n$ is the number of trials until the sequence 1, 1 occurs. Is this correct?

Comment: You can think of the process as a Markov chain with three states (0, 1 and 11) where 11 is an absorbing state. The time $K$ is the time till absorption into 11. Just consider the fact that before reaching 11, what happens next depends on whether your current observation is 0 or 1.

Comment: The hint given above is fully correct, but it is to note
that by putting  an absorbing barrier at "$11$" , the relevant counting will
provide the *Cumulative Probability over $n$*, that is the probability
that a string of length $n$ contains *at least one* appearence of the substring "$11$".

Comment: refer to [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466706) and [also to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045496)

Comment: I believe you meant the moment generating function of $K$?

Comment: Also, your last sentence is redundant and confusing because it defines $n$ as what $K$ already is (and the equality $K=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$ does not hold).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tau_0=\inf\{n>0: X_n=X_{n-1}=1\}$ (the quantity we are interested in) and $\tau_1=\inf\{n>0: X_n=1\mid X_{n-1}=1\}$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\tau_0] &= 1 + (1-p)\mathbb E[\tau_0] + p\mathbb E[\tau_1]\\
\mathbb E[\tau_01 &= 1 + (1-p)\mathbb E[\tau_0],\\
\end{align}
and hence
$$
\mathbb E[\tau_0] = \frac{1+p}{p^2},\quad \mathbb E[\tau_1] = \frac1{p^2}.
$$