# combinatorics: binary string

Tags: combinatorics, binary, regular-expressions

I am looking for an expression that uniquely determines the following set:
$S$ is the set of binary strings such that each block of $0$'s is congruent modulo $3$ to the length of block of $1$'s that follows it (if it exists)...that is,  (length of $0$) = (length of $1$) mod $3$.

I am thinking to start from $0^*(\{1\}\{1\}^*\{0\}\{0\}^*)^*1^*$, but soon I realize that, the length of block of $1$ is arbitrary, then I got stuck....Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate no. of binary strings containg substring “00”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466706/how-to-calculate-no-of-binary-strings-containg-substring-00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the words in the form $0^{n_1}1^{m_1}0^{n_2}1^{m_2} \dotsm$, your condition can be written as $n_k \equiv m_k \bmod 3$ for every $k > 0$. This leads to the followig regular expression
$$
\bigl((000)^*(111)^* + (000)^*0(111)^*1 + (000)^*00(111)^*11 \bigr)^* 0^*
$$